Meaning of ども in "[Noun] どもが”
Im trying to understand the following sentence and I get most of it but not what ども　or どもが　is doing (ive searched but i dont find info on this particular construction"

どいつもこいつも金と出世の亡者どもが！

Essentially it is saying, all of you are obsessed with money and success. So
どいつもこいつも Every single one of you
金と出世の亡者 Person obssesed or possessed by money and success
ga (you are)
But what i dont get is what domo is doing here. I cant seem to find any info so I would be very greatful for some insight here.
thanks


ども is 共 in kanji, and it's one of the plural suffixes in Japanese. It's similar to 達, but has an effect of lowering the status of the modified noun. 私共 is a humble and polite way of saying "we/us", but when it's used to refer to the listener, it sounds condescending and rude.
This が is more than just a subject marker. See: Why is が added at the end of この小娘が?

So どもが carries a strong nuance of "You bastards!".

I see, thanks a lot! that definitely puts me on the right path :)
